# Generic parameter 'D' could not be inferred [Swift]

Tags: swift, xcode, function, generics

```
import CryptoKit

func getAlgorithm(algo: String) {
  var algorithms = ["md5":Insecure.MD5.hash,
                    "sha1":Insecure.SHA1.hash,
                    "sha256":SHA256.hash,
                    "sha384":SHA384.hash,
                    "sha512":SHA512.hash]
  return algorithms[algo]
}
   
var algorithm: () = getAlgorithm(algo: "sha256")
```

[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvwiC.png)

The error: "Generic parameter 'D' could not be inferred" is happening on line 4, I am not really familiar with generics. That's why I'm asking this question here. Could any of you please explain what's wrong with this code? That would be greatly appreciated.

I wan't to be able to specify a hashing algorithm and use it multiple times instead of having to do a switch statement and having to call the function there. (For efficiency reasons)

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the error?

Comment: There a  number of issues here. First, each `.hash` is a function that takes a parameter of generic type conforming to [`DataProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dataprotocol). You have to specify the concrete type, otherwise the function `hash` on its own isn't fully defined. But even if you did that, each `.hash` function has a different return type, so they are completely different entities. How were you planning to use this dictionary to begin with?

Comment: @NewDev I'm trying to call the hash function from my variable hence I haven't fully defined it yet. I programmed this project in python before and in python it's possible to return a function from a dictionary.

Comment: @MatsOpdeBeeck, it is possible to return a function, but this function is generic - you need to define its generic parameter. But still, like I said, even if you did that, each `.hash` function has a different return value